# NameError in Controller due to wrong syntax in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

So I'm working on a project where there are tasks that make up a scavenger hunt. So when a user clicks on a particular hunt, I'd like the `show.html.erb` file to show the hunt as well as the tasks associated with that hunt. I've got the hunt and tasks models connected through `HuntTask.rb`.  I created the `HuntTask` model based off a suggestion here: [Has and Belongs to Many error - *_development.hunts_tasks' doesn't exist:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957719/has-and-belongs-to-many-error-development-hunts-tasks-doesnt-exist), but I'm still having trouble getting the hunt controller to make sense.

```
  def show
    @hunt = Hunt.find(params[:id])
    @title = @hunt.name    
    @tasks = @hunt.tasks.paginate(:page => params[:page]) 
  end
```

But then it throws up this error:

```
    NameError in HuntsController#show
    uninitialized constant Hunt::Hunttask
```

Here's what my models looks like:

```
class Hunt < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hunttasks
  has_many :tasks, :through => :hunttasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hunttasks
  has_many :hunts, :through => :hunttasks
end

class HuntTask < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :hunt, :class_name => "Hunt"
  belongs_to :task, :class_name => "Task"
```

I'm pretty sure that the name error is telling me that Rails can't find a table called `hunt`," which makes sense because the correct table is "hunts."  But I'm hesitant to change the third line of my show method,

```
@tasks = @hunt.tasks.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

because I want to specify that the `@tasks` method should pull all the tasks associated with this particular hunt being shown, not with all hunts.  I suppose I just don't understand the syntax I'm using in `@tasks`.

When I do add the `s` to `(@tasks = @hunts.tasks.paginate(:page => params[:page]) )`, I get a `NilClass` error.

```
NoMethodError in HuntsController#show
undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass
```

But I don't think tasks is supposed to be a method.  Or is it?

Any advice on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be:

```
class Hunt < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hunt_tasks
  has_many :tasks, :through => :hunt_tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hunt_tasks
  has_many :hunts, :through => :hunt_tasks
end

class HuntTask < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :hunt # the id for the association is in this table
  belongs_to :task
end
```

when you're doing something like `belongs_to :hunt, :class_name => "Hunt"`
 which seems pretty straight forward and you didn't need to do elsewhere, you should ask yourself why.

Comment: You were right.  I was missing the underscore.  The line that was raising the error was this one:   `@tasks = @hunt.tasks.paginate(:page => params[:page]) `.